# How to lock rotation for objects?

Tags: baba-is-you

I am making a recreation of [You are now Possessed by Lonebot](https://lonebot.itch.io/possessed), and I want to show the menu showing which move I have to do currently, but I can't figure out how to lock the rotation of the arrows, so that's my description for this. Oh and I also want it to be able to handle multiple objects of the same type (arrows and swords).

Comment: If you place the arrows down facing a certain direction, what would cause them to rotate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change which way an object is facing with [Directions](https://babaiswiki.fandom.com/wiki/Directions). IE: `ARROW IS LEFT` would make all arrows face left.

If you want to lock in a direction for a specific arrow, you could place each Arrow on the same space as a different [Letter](https://babaiswiki.fandom.com/wiki/Letters), use [Hide](https://babaiswiki.fandom.com/wiki/HIDE) to make the letters invisible, then use rules to specify each arrow's direction based on what letter it's on top of. For example: `ARROW ON A IS LEFT`, `ARROW ON B IS RIGHT`, `ARROW ON C IS DOWN`, etc.